# javaexe based program does not run normally on Windows 8.1

Tags: java, windows, windows-8.1, wrapper, javaexe

I created a program using javaexe, a wrapper for Java programs that allows them to be launched by an exe file. This program contains a service part, a taskbar part (they send messages one to another). The program purpose is to send SMS and the list of the SMS sent is available from the taskbar icon.

The program has been working since a few years on a Windows XP computer, but I would like to launch it from my Windows 8.1 laptop computer, and when I launch the EXE, the splash screen is displayed, the service is installed, but the icon in the taskbar does not appear, and the serviceInit method does not seem to be run.

Where does the problem come from? My computer uses Windows 8.1, with Avast! as antivirus and the Comodo firewall. I obviously tested my program having disabled these 2 security programs (Avast! and Comodo) but there is still the same problem.

Comment: What version of Java were you using on the XP machine?  I have seen similar problems moving older Java applications which need to be updated for new Java Virtual Machine.

Comment: Also take a look at the [troubleshooting tips for using Java on Windows 8](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/win8_faq.xml).

Comment: hello, the java version is 1.7.0_03 (on the winXP computer where it works), and on the laptop it is a java v1.8.0_25 x64. thanks

Comment: I also tried to launch the program with the win8 integrated firewall but without success

Comment: One possibility is that it requires Admin privileges to run.  So you may need to start it as Admin.

Comment: your .exe has an UAC manifest to run as admin or "asInvoke" ?

Comment: the applications that run automatically as Admin are blocked by windows, and must be manually confirmed to run

Comment: I did not mentionned this, but every time I launch the EXE, it is with a right-click and "run as admin"

Comment: @bb67 : where can I find the UAC manifest?

Comment: Is that your problem occurs only at the automatic launch of the service when windows start and the user log on ?

Comment: well, I did not tested it with a reboot since it already does not work after a manual launch...

Comment: I wonder why it could work after a reboot and not after a manual launch

Comment: @bb67 : I hope you did not thought I was sarcastic! Have you an other idea? I am stuck with this problem and it is for my work!

Comment: the JRE that you use on winXP is it 32bits or 64bits ? and which version of JavaExe (32bits or 64bits) did you use on your Windows 8.1 64bits ?

Answer (score 0):

I use also JavaExe for an interactive service and I tested it on Windows 8.1 Pro (32bits)
with JRE 1.7 and 1.8....and it works fine, manually and automatically (after reboot) : the service running and the taskbar running also and communicates.

My .exe isn't fixed to run always as admin. When I install the service, I right-click and run it "as admin".
But, if I fix the .exe to always run as admin, I just double-click on .exe to install the service, but the taskbar doesn't run automatically after reboot : Windows 8.1 block the applications that automatically run as admin when the user log on.

I tested also the examples of JavaExe (example8 and 23) and it also works.
Have you the same problem with JavaExe's examples ?